# Maximal free submodule over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, principal-ideal-domains

Let *M* be a f.g. module over a p.i.d. and *T(M)* be its torsion submodule. Then *M* is the direct sum of *T(M)* and of a free submodule *F*, unique up to isomorphism, and in addition which is a maximal free submodule. Conversely, let *F* be a maximal free submodule of *M* (which is a stronger condition than being of maximal rank). Is it true that *F* is a direct summand, so that *M* is the direct sum of *T(M)* and *F*?

Comment: By a maximal free submodule of M I mean a submodule which is maximal among all free submodules of M. The only maximal free submodule of Z is Z itself

Comment: Bourlés One observation to be made is that the set of all free submodules coincides with that of all submodules which intersect the torsion submodule trivially, so your problem can be reformulated as whether any module maximal among those intersecting $\mathrm{T}(M)$ trivially must be a direct summand or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is false in general, as we shall illustrate below by a counterexample. Before moving on two key observations are needed:

1. as I passingly mentioned in a comment to the original question, there is identity between the collection of submodules of $M$ which intersect $\mathrm{T}(M)$ trivially and the collection of free submodules. Clearly, if $N \leqslant_A M$ is free then $N \cap \mathrm{T}(M)=\mathrm{T}(N)=\{0_M\}$, since free modules over (commutative) integral domains are torsionless. On the other hand, by the same token any submodule $N$ that intersects the torsion submodule trivially must itself be torsionless. $M$ being finitely generated over the Noetherian ring $A$ means that $M$ itself is a Noetherian module, with the consequence that in particular $N$ is finitely generated. Since any torsionless finitely generated $A$-module is free, $N$ is in particular free. The problem can therefore be reformulated as analysing whether any submodule $N$ maximal among those which intersect $\mathrm{T}(M)$ trivially is a direct summand or not.
2. assuming that the submodule $L \leqslant_A M$ is maximal free and at the same time a direct summand, let us remark that it has a *unique* supplementary, namely the torsion submodule. Indeed, consider an arbitrary supplementary $P$ of $L$. Without proof we mention a very general result:

> **Lemma.** Let $A$ be an arbitrary ring, $S \leqslant_{\mathrm{Mon}} \mathrm{Z}(A)$ a *central* multiplicative system of $A$, $M$ a *left* $A$-module, $I$ an arbitrary index set and $N \in \mathscr{S}_{\operatorname{\mathit{A}-\mathrm{Mod}}}(M)^I$ a family of submodules whose (internal) sum is direct. Given any family $P \in \displaystyle\prod_{i \in I}\mathscr{S}_{\operatorname{\mathit{A}-\mathrm{Mod}}}(N_i)$ of submodules, the following relation holds between $S$-saturations:
> $$\mathrm{Sat}_S\left(\sum_{i \in I}P_i\right)=\sum_{i \in I}\left(\mathrm{Sat}_S(P_i) \cap N_i\right)$$

and apply this result to the particular case of submodules $\{0_M\} \leqslant_A L$ respectively $\{0_M\} \leqslant_A P$ and multiplicative system $A^{\times}\colon=A \setminus \{0_A\}$, yielding the conclusion that $\mathrm{T}(M)=\mathrm{Sat}_{A^{\times}}\left(\{0_M\}\right)=\left(\mathrm{Sat}_{A^{\times}}\left(\{0_M\}\right) \cap L\right)+\left(\mathrm{Sat}_{A^{\times}}\left(\{0_M\}\right) \cap P\right)=\mathrm{T}(L)+\mathrm{T}(P)=\mathrm{T}(P)$. Since $P$ is finitely generated over a principal ideal domain, its torsion submodule must admit a (free) supplementary $Q$ *in* $P$, and it follows that $L+Q$ and $\mathrm{T}(P)=\mathrm{T}(M)$ are supplementary in $M$. By maximality of $L$, it further follows that $Q \subseteq L+Q=L$, whence $Q \subseteq L \cap P=\{0_M\}$ and thus finally $P=\mathrm{T}(M)$.

Now on to the promised counterexample: consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$, where I am using the abbreviation $\mathbb{Z}_r\colon=\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ for any $r \in \mathbb{N}$. It is clear that $\mathrm{T}(M)=\{0\} \times \mathbb{Z}_4$. We argue that the submodule $N\colon=\mathbb{Z}\left(2, \overline{1}\right)$ is maximal free yet not a direct summand (the bar notation $\overline{m}$ denotes the residue class of $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ modulo $4$). The condition $N \cap \mathrm{T}(M)=\{0_M\}$ is easily verified. Consider a submodule $P \leqslant_{\mathbb{Z}} M$ such that $N \leqslant_{\mathbb{Z}} P$ and $P \cap \mathrm{T}(M)=\{0_M\}$. If $p \colon \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \to \mathbb{Z}$ denotes the canonical projection onto the left factor, we have $2\mathbb{Z}=p[N] \leqslant_{\mathbb{Z}} p[P] \leqslant_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}$, which gives the only options $p[P]=\mathbb{Z}$ or $p[P]=2\mathbb{Z}$. The former option leads to a contradiction, since $1 \in p[P]$ meant there existed $a \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ such that $(1, a) \in P$ and therefore $(2, 2a) \in P$. Since we also have $\left(2, \overline{1}\right) \in N \subseteq P$, it follows that $0_M \neq \left(0, 2a-\overline{1}\right) \in P \cap \mathrm{T}(M)$, which constitutes the contradiction (the fact that $\overline{1} \notin 2\mathbb{Z}_4=\left\{\overline{0}, \overline{2}\right\}$ is crucial here). We thus necessarily have $p[P]=2\mathbb{Z}$, so for any $x \in P$ there exist $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $t \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ such that $x=(2n, t)$. As we also have $n\left(2, \overline{1}\right)=\left(2n, \overline{n}\right) \in P$, we infer that $\left(0, t-\overline{n}\right) \in P \cap \mathrm{T}(M)=\{0_M\}$ whence $t=\overline{n}$ and thus $x \in N$. This proves the equality $P=N$ and establishes $N$ as maximal among those submodules which intersect $\mathrm{T}(M)$ trivially. However, the second observation tells us that $N$ cannot be a direct summand: indeed, if this were the case it would necessarily follow that $N+\mathrm{T}(M)=M$, whereas in our case $N+\mathrm{T}(M)=2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_4<_{\mathbb{Z}} M$ is a proper submodule.

Answer (score -1):

Consider $M=\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $F=2\mathbb{Z}$, the sequence $0\rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$ does not split and $2\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal.

Comment: How is $2\mathbb{Z}$ maximal in $\mathbb{Z}$? I think maximal in the question needs to be interpreted as allowing $F$ to be the whole of $M$, else the answer is not very meaningful.

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide Indeed, the question poster has made it explicit that he uses the syntagm "maximal free submodule" to refer to maximal elements in the inclusion-ordered set of *all* free submodules (including therefore the ambient module were it free).